Pastry dough no firmness
I made a rough puff pastry dough but after the first sit in the fridge it's very soft it's not wet or moist but it's soft and fully I can stretch it real easily and there's no firmness to it at all what did I do wrong or can I fix it can I save it I was making apple turnovers please help

What was the recipe, and were there any substitutions? Did you measure by volume or weight?
